# Fire another thread inside For Loop iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

is there any equivalent function to thread::yield() in the iOS 4.2 ?

```
for ()
{
    thread::yield();//go track other events
}
```

I tried to use `NSRunLoop` but I'm beginner and I'm not full aware of it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you could use the `NSThread` method `sleepForTimeInterval:` with a very small interval to do effectively the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, but if the other thread finishes task within this timeInterval Current thread would still wait for that time to lapse doing nothing. I would recommend using NSOperationQueue. Your answer is correct for the question asked +1

Comment: thanks for reply but this code freeze screen till the for finish its work, what i need is to let the device do other events like rendering and user inputs normaly while this for loop is working.

Comment: @AlaaEldin Make sure you are performing all UI operations on main thread.

Comment: @Alaa Eldin - I was under the impression that the thread you were yielding was not the UI thread.  If you need to do long running work, you shouldn't do it in the UI thread and should use an NSOperationQueue as 0x8badf00d suggests

Comment: I solved it using `[NSThread Performselector:@selector(funname) withobject:functioninput] ; `
previous worked well on iphone 4
still searching for another options for iphone 3

Comment: `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(funname:) withObject:CurrentViewController];`
has solved the problem with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, just do the work you want in a thread. Let the OS schedule things.

It's also easier not to explicitly use threads, but instead use Grand Central Dispatch in some form — NSOperationQueue is a good way to do so.